# What's the difference between "early in the morning", in the morning, "late at night" and at night?

Tags: grammar, expressions, syntactic-analysis

Why use early in the morning instead of just in the morning? And why use late at night instead of at night?
Is there some kind of difference in the way your message is understood?

Answer (score 3):

It is reasonably self-explanatory. Morning is generally considered the hours 6AM to 12PM. Night is usually 6PM to 6AM (we will disregard daylight savings etc. for this example). Most people regard night as 'the time when it is dark', and morning from the hours when the sun has risen (until the afternoon). However, some people will actually refer to the 'early morning' as hours from 12AM-6AM and hence this can be a little confusing.

Thus, to answer your question, 'early in the morning' would refer to earlier hours of the morning (i.e. around 12AM-6AM). Again, late at night is when most people will begin sleeping (around 8PM-12AM) and also 12AM-6AM the following day (if you consider this still as night, since it is dark). It's a confusing topic to understand, as there are not set rules about them, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I would argue that the night/morning division is earlier, maybe 3 AM.

Answer (score 0):

In the morning = before noon.

Early in the morning = in the first hours of the time that most people are up and about.

At night = during the hours of darkness, or when most people are in bed.

Late at night = in the latter part of the evening, when some people are probably already in bed.